# Apriori algorithm using Pandas

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, pandas, data-mining

I want to optimize my Apriori algorithm for speed:

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

trans=pd.read_table('output.txt', header=None,index_col=0)

def apriori(trans, support=0.01, minlen=1):
    ts=pd.get_dummies(trans.unstack().dropna()).groupby(level=1).sum()

    collen, rowlen  =ts.shape

    #-------------Max leng (not used)
    #tssum=ts.sum(axis=1)
    #maxlen=int(tssum.loc[tssum.idxmax()])


    pattern = []
    for cnum in range(minlen, rowlen+1):
        for cols in combinations(ts, cnum):
            patsup = ts[list(cols)].all(axis=1).sum()
            patsup=float(patsup)/collen
            pattern.append([",".join(cols), patsup])
    sdf = pd.DataFrame(pattern, columns=["Pattern", "Support"])
    results=sdf[sdf.Support >= support]

    return results
```

**When you input a dataframe of transactions:**

> ```
> >>> trans
>         1  2    3    4
> 0                     
> 11      a  b    c  NaN
> 666     a  d    e  NaN
> 10101   b  c    d  NaN
> 1010    a  b    c    d
> 414147  b  c  NaN  NaN
> 10101   a  b    d  NaN
> 1242    d  e  NaN  NaN
> 101     a  b    c  NaN
> 411     c  d    e  NaN
> 444     a  b    c  NaN
>
> [10 rows x 4 columns]
> ```

**It will yield:**

> ```
> Ap=apriori(trans)
> print Ap
> >>> 
>    Pattern  Support
> 0        a      0.6
> 1        b      0.7
> 2        c      0.7
> 3        d      0.6
> 4        e      0.3
> 5      a,b      0.5
> 6      a,c      0.4
> 7      a,d      0.3
> 8      a,e      0.1
> 9      b,c      0.6
> 10     b,d      0.3
> 12     c,d      0.3
> 13     c,e      0.1
> 14     d,e      0.3
> 15   a,b,c      0.4
> 16   a,b,d      0.2
> 18   a,c,d      0.1
> 20   a,d,e      0.1
> 21   b,c,d      0.2
> 24   c,d,e      0.1
> ```

I want to know if this can be optimized further so that it can run faster on large datasets.  I also want to know if there a way to use purely Pandas without combinations from itertools.

Comment: You may want to check out pyFIM for an alternative approach: http://www.borgelt.net/pyfim.html

Comment: how your output.txt dataset looks

Answer (score 6):

First off, this is just a part of the Apriori algorithm. Here, you're just finding frequent itemsets. Apriori continues to find association rules in those itemsets.

Also, using `combinations()` like this is not optimal. For example, if we know that the combination `AB` does not enjoy reasonable support, we do not need to consider any combination that contains `AB` anymore (`ABC`, `ABD`, etc. will all be infrequent as well). Your algorithm does not take this into consideration.

This means that your algorithm will check all the possible combinations (2<sup>n</sup>, where n is the number of possible items), while in fact we can prune the search tree as above and reduce this complexity drastically (depending on the density of the dataset).